# Data sets for Formal Concept Analysis

Tags: galois-theory, lattice-orders, data-analysis

I am currently completing a postgrad degree in Information Systems Management and have been given a thesis topic that relates to Formal Concept Analysis.

The objective is compare open-source software that is able to read data and represent this in a lattice diagram (an example application is that of Concept Explorer). Additionally, the performance of these tools need to be compared with one another, with varying data-set sizes etc.

The main problem I'm experiencing is finding data sets that are compliant with these tools that are big enough to test the limits of each application, as well as figuring out how to accurately measure things such as CPU time taken to draw the lattice diagram and other similar measures. Data for formal contexts generally follow a binary relationship, such as a cross table that shows how attributes and objects can be related.

As such, my question is where would I find such data and how would I be able to manipulate that data to be usable with software like Concept Explorer.

P.S. I am new here, so not sure if this is posted in the right place!

Comment: As far as I understand about FCA, complicated data generates a messy concept lattice which is not human-readable. So I feel no practical data suitable for FCA is big enough. Do you have any particular reason that you don't use randomly generated binary tables to test such limits?

Comment: The use of randomly generated tables is a last resort according to my supervisor, but may be necessary considering the lack of helpful resources available...